# Take input from user in php nlp similarity

Tags: php, nlp, cosine-similarity

i am following below code for similarity
how to take user input for following script can anyone please help ?

code copied from documentation
http://php-nlp-tools.com/documentation/similarity.html

```
'''
<?php   
include ('vendor/autoload.php');

use \NlpTools\Tokenizers\WhitespaceTokenizer;
use \NlpTools\Similarity\JaccardIndex;
use \NlpTools\Similarity\CosineSimilarity;
use \NlpTools\Similarity\Simhash;

$s1 = "Please allow me to introduce myself
    I'm a man of wealth and tase";
$s2 = "Hello, I love you, won't you tell me your name
    Hello, I love you, let me jump in your game";

$tok = new WhitespaceTokenizer();
$J = new JaccardIndex();
$cos = new CosineSimilarity();
$simhash = new Simhash(16); // 16 bits hash

$setA = $tok->tokenize($s1);
$setB = $tok->tokenize($s2);

printf (
"
Jaccard:  %.3f
Cosine:   %.3f
Simhash:  %.3f
SimhashA: %s
SimhashB: %s
",
$J->similarity(
    $setA,
    $setB
),
$cos->similarity(
    $setA,
    $setB
),
$simhash->similarity(
    $setA,
    $setB
),
$simhash->simhash($setA),
$simhash->simhash($setB)
);
?>
'''
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: i want to take input in html form instead of writing in script !

Comment: and fetch 2nd string (s2) from database to compare with s1